# TableAdapter data has changed but property "has Changes" stays at "false" so udate does nothing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, updates, tableadapter, savechanges

It's mostly in the title...
I'm using VB (obviously, see below), but I'm a total beginner with visual studio.

Here is the test code I'm using (it is a simple test button I designed to test the problem I have in the code elsewhere):

```
    Private Sub Test_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Test.Click
        Dim FDBdataset As New FDBDataSet()
        Dim FDBTableAdapter As New FDBDataSetTableAdapters.T_PicturesTableAdapter
        For Each row As DataRow In FDBTableAdapter.GetData()
            row.BeginEdit()
            If row("id").ToString = 58672.ToString Then
                row.BeginEdit()
                Console.Write("Previous Value = " & row("ImgFileName").ToString)
                row("ImgFileName") = "Tagada"
                row.EndEdit()
                Console.WriteLine(", Current Row Value = " & row("ImgFileName").ToString & " - HasChanges : " & FDBdataset.HasChanges())
            End If
        Next
        FDBTableAdapter.Update(FDBdataset)
```

The output in the console is:

```
Previous Value = Aphidecta_obliterata_58672, Current Row Value = Tagada - HasChanges : False
```

I don't understand what is wrong and how to correct it...
I would be very grateful for some help here !

TableAdapter seems set up correctly, and I can read from it, parse rows; display field values, etc...
Update method reports as being correctly set up by the datasource designer.
Code runs without errors but does not affect the DB content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you think that `FDBdataset` has any changes in it? Where are you making any changes to it? You have this:

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In FDBTableAdapter.GetData()
```

and `GetData` returns a new `DataTable`, so you're making change to that `DataTable` completely independent of `FDBdataset`. Use one or the other but not both.

Based on the code you have there, you don't need the `DataSet`. You can just use the `DataTable` returnd by `GetData`:

```vb
Dim adapter As New FDBDataSetTableAdapters.T_PicturesTableAdapter
Dim table = FDBTableAdapter.GetData()

For Each row In table
    If row.id = 58672 Then
        row.ImgFileName = "Tagada"
    End If
Next

adapter.Update(table)
```

Notice that I tidied up your code a lot too. If you're going to use a typed `DataSet` then use it.

If you actually do need a `DataSet` for some reason then make the changes to it, not an unrelated `DataTable`:

```vb
Dim data As New FDBDataSet
Dim adapter As New FDBDataSetTableAdapters.T_PicturesTableAdapter

adapter.Fill(data)

For Each row In data.T_Pictures
    If row.id = 58672 Then
        row.ImgFileName = "Tagada"
    End If
Next

adapter.Update(data)
```

That second code snippet may need some adjustments but I think it should work.

So, the moral of the story is that the `Fill` method populates an existing `DataTable`, which can be part of a `DataSet` but doesn't have to be, while the `GetData` method creates a new `DataTable`, populates it and returns it. That new `DataTable` is not part of any `DataSet`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer in detail what must be a very basic request (real noob here !). I now understand a lot better my mistake and the confusion I made between dataset and datatable. Now I have another error that comes up: 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.' but as far as I can tell the dataset is configure correctly with the update statement defined...

Comment: And, yes the table does have a primary key.

Comment: @user44183, if this answer addresses the issue you asked about then you should accept it. If you have another question about a different issue then you should post a new question, with all and only the information relevant to that issue.